# I am trying to upload image using angular but getting error

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting error while uploading image,server throws an error `Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined`,i'm using nodejs as backend server but when i send the image through postman, image is successfully getting stored in mongodb

i have gone through various post on stack overflow but still getting error,i don't know where i'm missing

// html code

```
<label for="InputImage">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" title="image" 
(change)="handleImageInput($event)"
 class="form-control" id="InputImage">
```

// component.ts

```
imageToUpload: File;

handleImageInput($event) {
this.imageToUpload = $event.target.files[0];
}

addPackage() {
const obj = this.onSubmit();
const dataToSend = {
  ...obj,
  title: this.packageForm.controls.title.value,
  price: this.packageForm.controls.price.value,
};

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Image',this.imageToUpload,this.imageToUpload.name);

this.submitted = true;
if (this.packageForm.valid) {
  this.submitting = true;
  this.submitText = 'Submitting';
  this.packageService.addPackage(dataToSend,formData).subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res;
    if (this.data.status == true) {
      this.toasterService.showSuccess('Package added Successfully');
      this.reset();
    }
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  }, () => {
    this.submitting = false;
    this.submitText = 'Submit';
  }
  );
} else {
  this.toasterService.showFailure('Please fill all the fields');
}
}
```

// service.ts

```
addPackage(packageData: IProduct,imageData) {
console.log(packageData);
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'spectrum/package/addPackage', 
{
  title: packageData.title,
  productNames: packageData.productNames,
  productQuantities: packageData.productQuantities,
  price: packageData.price
},imageData)
}
```

Comment: it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constructing the image data rightly with use of the FormData object, but you shouldn't send it using the third parameter of the HttpClient. [The third parameter is the 'options' argument, not the body](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post). When sending the data using FormData you should send all data using the FormData object. On the serverside you also need to specify on the endpoint that the request content-type is 'multipart/data-form', you can't mix 'application/json' and 'multipart/data-form' on one endpoint. You should use only one of the two.

Comment: Thanks joep kockelkorn for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add headers, try this

```
addPackage(packageData: IProduct,imageData) {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');            
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(packageData);
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'spectrum/package/addPackage', 
    {
      title: packageData.title,
      productNames: packageData.productNames,
      productQuantities: packageData.productQuantities,
      price: packageData.price
    },imageData, options)
    }
```

Hope useful.

Comment: Thanks khalifa for your contribution